# Jquery function calling sequence

Tags: jquery

I'm newbie to Jquery and saw this piece of code in a book.
I'm trying to understand how hideCode() is being executed.

This is my understanding of the sequence of evets thats going to happen:

1. Document gets loaded and its ready to perform the jquery function.
2. When the guess_box is clicked run checkForCode() function.
3. hideCode() function runs.

Is this correct?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".guess_box").click(checkForCode);
   function getRandom(num) {
       var my_num = Math.floor(Math.random() * num);
       return my_num;
   }
   var hideCode = function() {
       var numRand = getRandom(4);
       $(".guess_box").each(function(index, value) { 
           if(numRand == index){
               $(this).append("<span id='has_discount'></span>");
               return false;
           }
       });
   }
   hideCode();
   function checkForCode() {
       var discount;
       if($.contains(this, document.getElementById("has_discount"))) {
          var my_num = getRandom(5);
          discount = "<p>Your Discount is " + my_num + "%</p>";
       } else {
           discount = "<p>Sorry, no discount this time!</p>" ;
       }
       $(this).append(discount);
       $(".guess_box").each(function() {
           $(this).unbind('click');
       });
```

Comment: IMHO, add alert /console.debug in beteeen lines and see in what order they are executing. That will help you to understand the sequence of execution.

Comment: Your code is pretty hard to read with 1-space indentation. I suggest you to use 4 spaces.

Comment: hideCode is called before your click.

Comment: Can you trim this code a bit? I don't think we need all this information.

Comment: hideCode is going to be called on document.ready since it is not inside any other function

Comment: I've formatted the code for readability (indents and spacing). Please make sure code is indented properly when you post it, because the previous version was very hard to read.

Comment: thanks guys..I got the flow now with you description and alert debugs..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless there's more code we're not seeing, `hideCode` is called only once, when the page loads. `checkForCode` doesn't run until `guess_box` is clicked. The sequence is:

1. Document gets loaded.
2. `checkForCode` gets bound to `guess_box`'s click event, but it doesn't run yet.
3. `hideCode` runs.

Comment: What is the difference between $(this).append("<span id='has_discount'></span>");  and $(this).append(discount); 
  Why is the first append invisible whereas the second append is visible.

Comment: Probably because there's nothing in it. Try `$(this).append("<span id='has_discount'>here is some text</span>");` instead. Also, if there are fewer than 5 guess_box elements, `numRand == index` might never be true.